# Best way to access the correct IPv6 address my laptop sens

Tags: routes, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I checked a load of questions before writing this but none seemed to answer the question.

Can someone tell me whether this site https://findipv6.com/find/ is converting the IPv6 address back to IPv4 before doing a geolocation test. The thing is it's pretty accurate with location but as I don't seem to have an IPv6 address from any "What is my IP address" site like:
http://icanhazip.com/ > returns IPv4
http://ipv6.icanhazip.com/ (DNS errors, site cannot be reached)
https://www.iplocation.net/ > no IPv6, Puts me in Manchester, the wrong end of the country by a few hundred miles
https://www.where-am-i.co/my-ip-location > Puts me in Central London way off by 30 miles or so, ipconfig only outputs IPv4.

These sites and other ones only show an IPv4 address. So is the site that reportedly is getting my details from my IPv6 address (which I don't seem to have), just reverse engineering the address back to IPv4 and using a more correct geoIP database?

The thing is, if I had a static IPv6 address it wouldn't change, or shouldn't, and it wouldn't be the same as an IPv4 address converted to IPv6 format surely? I can do that with this function that gives me the exact same IPv6 address as this site when I put my IPv4 address into it > https://findipv6.com/ipv4-to-ipv6/

```
function ConvertToIPv6(ip)
{
    var a = ip.split('.');
    var s = "";
    for(var x=0;x<a.length;x++)
    {
        let n = parseInt(a[x]);         
        let p = n.toString(16);         
        if(s.length==4)
        {
            s = s + ":" + p;                
        }else{
            s = s + p;              
        }           
    }
    return "::ffff:"+s;
}
```

The reason I want to know is that I was given a message on a site with an IPv6 address making me fill out a CAPTCHA due to "Unusual Tradffic", however every "What is my IP" site I go to says I don't have an IPv6 address. Plus surely converting IPv4 decimal to HEX format does not make it a REAL IPv6 assignment that my router has been given to the outside world as the whole point of IPv6 is that everything has a fixed address is it not?

Comment: You cannot convert addressing between IPv4 and IPv6 because the addressing is incompatible as are the two protocols. "_the whole point of IPv6 is that everything has a fixed address is it not?_" No, the point is that every host gets a public address, not that it is fixed. You can see if your host has IPv6 at https://test-ipv6.com/.

Comment: So are you saying even when IPv6 is standard all our routers will still get changing Ipv6 addresses when we reboot them like DCHP now with IPv4 if they are not fixed? That page says I do not have an IPv6 address just like the other pages. So that page that showed my IPv4 address converted to IPv6 is just converting decimal to HEX like the JS function and its not using an IPv6 DB like it claims, to get my location but using IPv4 and using a MaxMind type geoIP lookup. Thanks for the page.

Comment: "_So are you saying even when IPv6 is standard all our routers will still get changing Ipv6 addresses when we reboot them like DCHP now with IPv4 if they are not fixed?_" That depends on your ISP. Some will do that. Remember that residential ISP contracts prohibit running services to the public Internet, and that strategy helps prevent that. Geolocation is crap; it is really just guessing.

Comment: Also, understand that IPv6 does not just assign a public address to your router the way you get with IPv4. You will get a large IPv6 prefix from which you assign public IPv6 addresses to _every_ host in your network, restoring the IP end-to-end paradigm.

Comment: Seems kike guessing to me, I don't know what Databases they are using that one site can put me in Manchester and another in Central London, opposite ends of the country from the same IP, but that is why I asked about the site that reportedly showed my IPv6 address as it almost got me right to the town from a the same IP but they claimed it was an IPv6 map, but if they just converted IPv4 to IPv6 like my JS function then they r lying n just used the IPv4 address as the IPv6 address isn't a real IPv6 designation. Thanks for explaining it though,